# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

In one of my java code where I am trying to call alter table add partitions by using hive-metastore-2.1.1.jar getting below error. Yes, I am using all other required libraries.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/Table;Z)V
at com.uber.hoodie.hive.HoodieHiveClient.updateLastCommitTimeSynced(HoodieHiveClient.java:582)
at com.uber.hoodie.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:111)
at com.uber.hoodie.hive.HiveSyncTool.syncHoodieTable(HiveSyncTool.java:68)
at com.uber.hoodie.hive.HiveSyncTool.main(HiveSyncTool.java:189)
```

Let me know if anyone faced same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using right version of of hive meta store jar solved the problem : hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar